# Creating tabs with different heights in Android

Tags: android, android-layout

How I can create the following layout?

[image]

Comment: ya its possible. give your image as transparent in top for normal.

Comment: Please see that the layout uses two different custom dividers between tabs. Also shade tabs next to the selected tab. Is it possible to build this layout in android?

Answer (score 0):

Give those tabs which has not been selected, a background that their top part is transparent and pretends to be shorter than the selected one.